# Trying to extend but swap partition is showing as Unknown in Gparted, shows proper from fdisk

Tags: partition, swap, gparted

I was trying to do a simple hard drive extend through GParted but was unable to because it shows my swap as unknown. Running this on a CentOS system, sda1 is ext3 and the swap is sda2. The unallocated is behind the swap, so im unable to get to it until I can move the swap to the end. However, since Gparted is showing the swap as "Unknown" it will not let me modify it. Have yall ever seen this before?

Here is a screenshot from the GParted interface showing details on the partitions and also below is the output of FDISK on the server itself.

[image: GParted Screenshot]

```
Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders, total 209715200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00069ccb

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   134219775    67108864   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       134219776   135682047      731136   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Do yall have any ideas on this? Since it is just swap should i be able to format it in GParted? Or, is there any other way of just extending SDA1? Im searching for some answers but wanted to post about it here as well. This is on a production server so I definitely want to be certain about getting it right. :)

Thanks in advance for your consideration! :)

EDIT: It looks like if the swap is encrypted it will show as Unknown -- but I can't seem to find any information on how to extend if the swap is encrypted. There is no LVM going on here, just a regular linux native partition. ID: 83 and swap is 82.

Comment: Just an update -- I think that in the this case I can just remove the swap partition and recreate it at the end of the resize process. Since it is just swap space, I believe that should be fine. Im going to test it on a clone and see if everything goes smoothly.